# Pass information between directive and controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the next directive

```
  angular
  .module('01')
  .directive('tableSortable', tableSortable);

/** @ngInject */
function tableSortable() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  templateUrl: 'app/components/tabla/tableSortable.html',
  scope: {
    columns: '=',
    data: '=',
    sort: '=',
    onclickRow: '='
  }
```

and I have the next html that shows a table

```
<tbody>
<tr  ng-click="click(object)" ng-repeat="object in data | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
  <td
    ng-repeat="key in object"
    ng-if="key != '$$hashKey'" >
    {{object[columns[$index].variable] | customFilter : getFilterOfColumn(columns[$index].variable)}}
  </td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
```

I have this other html where I call the directive

```
  <table-sortable onclick-row="main.onclickRow(msg)"
    columns="main.columnsBusquedas" data="main.rowsBusquedas" sort="main.sortBusquedas">
    </table-sortable>
```

And this controller with a function onclickRow(msg) where I want to take the row that the users click on

```
function onclickRow(msg){
  $log.debug(msg);
}
```

This code didn't work... Could you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the ng-click in the template be calling onclickRow(...) rather than click(...)? And also I think you need to pass the object parameter via an object {msg: object}

Comment: @jose did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your directive part where you bind function, you should use `&` instead of `=`

```
function tableSortable() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  templateUrl: 'app/components/tabla/tableSortable.html',
  scope: {
    columns: '=',
    data: '=',
    sort: '=',
    click: '&onclickRow' // this how we call function from directive...
  }
```

In HTML change your `ng-click` like below..

```
<tbody>
<tr  ng-click="click({'msg':object})" ng-repeat="object in data | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
  <td
    ng-repeat="key in object"
    ng-if="key != '$$hashKey'" >
    {{object[columns[$index].variable] | customFilter : getFilterOfColumn(columns[$index].variable)}}
  </td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
```